# Pseudo-class :active not working correctly in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, pseudo-class

CSS:

```
a:link { color: green;}
a:active {color: orange;}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#">testing</a>
```

[Here is JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BMHUz/123/)

Pseudo-class :active still active after mouse button is clicked on the link, dragged away and released.
How to make the link color return to normal after release the mouse button?

I'm using Firefox 14.
It works fine in Chrome.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with FF 15.0.1.

Comment: Try to click the link, hold the mouse button then drag away and release the button and you will see the problem, link color still orange.It should be green afted the mouse button is released

Comment: After I drag away and release the color goes back to green.  Firefox nightly on Mac.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky Perhaps it's Windows-specific. Reported [bug 865409](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=865409).

Answer (score 2):

If you set your "active" colour on `:focus:hover` it will have the closest effect to what you want, although it won't be exactly the same as in Chrome in that the colour you set will appear when the link is focused and hovered but not when the mouse button is down.

However, if the thing you dislike most is that the "active" colour remains after the mouse is released, you can at least prevent that from happening by setting your "normal" link colour on `:focus`. The link does remain focused after it's been clicked, dragged off, and released - you can test this by doing it then pressing enter.

You may find examples (and information) on [this page](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/tests/css2/sec05-11-03.htm) - note the link colours when you hold and release the mouse; they correspond to the `a:hover`, `a:focus`, `a:focus:hover`, and `a:active` rules for that page.

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/BMHUz/127/](http://jsfiddle.net/BMHUz/127/) Its not work, the link stays the same color when i clicked it. It work in Chrome, though

Comment: Ah, I see!  You should use `:focus:hover` for the "active" colour, and put your "normal" colour on `:focus`. Check out the page I linked for a demo. I will update my answer. edit: hm, except one quirk is that the link will change colour when it's hovered and focused, but when the mouse button isn't down.

Answer (score 0):

I would instead use: a:hover:focus.
You get a new background-color when hovering, and a new link text color when clicking (focusing). And if you just downclick the link, and then pull the mouse away before upclicking, the new link text color will disappear.